# How to extract time from DateTime to have access to only the time in Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to extract the time from a DateTime example 2022-02-26 10:00:00 UTC  I want to return only the 10:00:00 from it.  Please help Using Rails v.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `strftime` method and passing `"%H:%M:%S"` format to it

```rb
%H - Hour of the day, 24-hour clock, zero-padded (00..23)
%k - Hour of the day, 24-hour clock, blank-padded ( 0..23)
%I - Hour of the day, 12-hour clock, zero-padded (01..12)

%M - Minute of the hour (00..59)

%S - Second of the minute (00..59)

%P - Meridian indicator, lowercase (``am'' or ``pm'')
%p - Meridian indicator, uppercase (``AM'' or ``PM'')
```

```rb
date = DateTime.now
date.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

# Output 07:44:10
```

Or if you need to have all segment separately you can extract hours, minutes and seconds like this:

```rb
date = DateTime.now

hour = date.hour # 07
minute = date.minute # 44
second = date.second # 10

# and you can interpolate
time = "#{hour}:#{minute}:#{second}"
```